# How should you do page redirects on action completion in flux based react using react-router and hashHistory

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

The primary problem is that doing a `history.push()` as part of a dispatch is not allowed because you can't do a dispatch within a dispatch. As an alternative to actually doing the redirect in the action function itself I'm currently passing callback functions to action methods to do calls to history methods. I don't think this is a good way to do things and I'm looking for a better way to do it. I'm doing this is in quite a few places including in the case of getting 401 errors - I clear session info and go to the login page. Here is how my code looks.

client.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router";

import CreateEntity from "./pages/CreateEntity";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import Entity from "./pages/Entity";


const app = document.getElementById('app');


ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard}></Route>
      <Route path="createEntity" component={CreateEntity}></Route>
      <Route path="entity/:name" component={Entity}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
app);
```

pages/Entity.js

```
import React from "react";
import * as EntityActions from "../actions/EntityActions";
import EntityStore from "../stores/EntityStore";


export default class Entity extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.finishDelete = this.finishDelete.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      description: undefined,
      name: undefined,
      id: undefined,
    };
  }

  delete() {
    EntityActions.deleteProject('mbrady', this.state.id, this.finishDelete)
  }

  finishDelete() {
    this.props.history.push("dashboard")
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    EntityStore.on("change", this.getProject);
    this.refresh()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    EntityStore.removeListener("change", this.getProject);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" onClick={this.delete.bind(this)}>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

actions/EntityActions.js

```
import dispatcher from "../dispatcher";
import axios from "axios";
import * as config from '../AppConfig'

export function deleteEntity(user, id, delete_callback) {
  dispatcher.dispatch({type: "DELETE_ENTITY"});
  const url = "http://localhost:"+port+"/"+config.appName+"/some_url";
  axios.delete(url)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatcher.dispatch({type:"DELETE_ENTITY_FULFILLED", payload: response.data});
      console.log(delete_callback)
      delete_callback(response.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatcher.dispatch({type:"DELETE_ENTITY_FAILED", payload: err})
    })
}
```

stores/EntityStore.js

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

import dispatcher from "../dispatcher";


class CurrentProjectStore extends EventEmitter {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.project = undefined;
  }

  handleActions(action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case "DELETE_PROJECT": {
        break;
      }
      case "DELETE_PROJECT_FAILED": {
        break;
      }
      case "DELETE_PROJECT_FULFILLED": {
        this.project = undefined
        break;
      }
    }
  }

}

const projectStore = new CurrentProjectStore;
dispatcher.register(projectStore.handleActions.bind(projectStore));

export default projectStore;
```